# AppwriteRealtime: Allow self-signed certificate , subscription: null

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cross-platform, appwrite

I had a problem with Real Time messages in Appwrite with Flutter, the subcription was null, but I think all setups were true because I have used a likewise code for another part of my project
here is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    UserModel copyOfUser = userModel;

    return Scaffold(
      body: ref.watch(getLatestUserProfileDataProvider).when(
            data: (data) {
              if (data.events.contains(
                'databases.*.collections.${AppWriteConstants.usersCollection}.documents.${copyOfUser.uid}.update',
              )) {
                copyOfUser = UserModel.fromMap(data.payload);
              }
              return UserProfile(user: copyOfUser);
            },
            error: (error, st) => ErrorText(
              error: error.toString(),
            ),
            loading: () {
              return UserProfile(user: copyOfUser);
            },
          ),
    );
  }
```

```
final getLatestUserProfileDataProvider = StreamProvider((ref) {
  final userAPI = ref.watch(userAPIProvider);
  return userAPI.getLatestUserProfileData();
});
```

```
  @override
  Stream<RealtimeMessage> getLatestUserProfileData() {
    return _realtime.subscribe([
      'databases.${AppWriteConstants.databaseId}.collections.${AppWriteConstants.usersCollection}.documents'
    ]).stream;
  }
```

Comment: Are you subscribing anywhere else as well? Are you unsubscribing/closing anywhere else with the same _realtime instance?

Comment: I have successfully fixed this issue by creating a new instance of the RealTime to register